# How to pass X-Auth-Token with Meteor's HTTP.call?

Tags: meteor, http-headers

How to pass `X-Auth-Token` with Meteor's `HTTP.call`?

E.g. to do something like this:

```
curl -X GET \
--header "X-Auth-Token: 1234567890abcdeff978d137bc01a2" \
https://example.com/api/call
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer on [Meteor's forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/http-get-x-auth-token-question/8552):

```
options = {
  headers: { 'X-Auth-Token' : '1234567890abcdeff978d137bc01a2' }
}
```

A bit more elaborated, in CoffeeScript:

```
res = HTTP.call 'GET', 'https://example.com/api/call',
  headers:
    'X-Auth-Token': auth_token
  params:
    a: 1
    b: 2
```

Comment: Thanks @gauka for the solution :-).